# Header php not exactly in place

Tags: html, css, layout, header, position

I'm including my header and footer with PHP. But the problem is that header doesn't always stay in it's place (horizantally). I want it to be stable on every page but it keeps moving left and right about some pixels. And also the content is not always in it's place, it's moving a little left or right on one of the pages. If you see this example, you can understand it better.
See the difference between those two pages:
1- http://www.altayda.com/test2/
2- http://www.altayda.com/test2/about.php

And here are the codes. Thanks in advance:

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>psdtowebindex12323.psd</title>
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
       <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="frameworkmodified.js"></script>

</head>

    <body>

   <div id="header"><?php include 'header.php'; ?></div>


   <div id="container">

    <ul id="filter"><hr size=1><br />
        <li class="current"><a href="#">All</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Poster Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Branding</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Illustration</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Painting</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Print Design</a></li>
        <br /><br />
        <hr size=1>
    </ul>

    <ul id="portfolio">

        <li class="poster-design"><a class="image" href="#"><span class="rollover" ></span> 
<img class="imgborder" src="images/politician.png" alt="" height="156" width="263" /></a></li>
        <li class="poster-design"><a class="image" href="#"><span class="rollover" ></span> 
<img class="imgborder" src="images/recycle.png" alt="" height="156" width="263" /></a></li>
        <li class="poster-design"><a class="image" href="#"><span class="rollover" ></span> 
<img class="imgborder" src="images/women.png" alt="" height="156" width="263" /></a></li>
        <li class="poster-design"><a class="image" href="#"><span class="rollover" ></span> 
<img class="imgborder" src="images/warwomen.png" alt="" height="156" width="263" /></a></li>
        <li class="poster-design"><a class="image" href="#"><span class="rollover" ></span> 
<img class="imgborder" src="images/joy.png" alt="" height="156" width="263" /></a></li>
        <li class="poster-design"><a class="image" href="#"><span class="rollover" ></span> 
<img class="imgborder" src="images/bombs.png" alt="" height="156" width="263" /></a></li>
        <li class="branding"><a class="image" href="#"><span class="rollover" ></span> 
<img class="imgborder" src="images/mir.png" alt="" height="156" width="263" /></a></li>
        <li class="illustration"><a class="image" href="#"><span class="rollover" ></span> 
<img class="imgborder" src="images/vader.png" alt="" height="156" width="263" /></a></li>
        <li class="illustration"><a class="image" href="#"><span class="rollover" ></span> 
<img class="imgborder" src="images/mario.png" alt="" height="156" width="263" /></a></li>
        <li class="painting"><a class="image" href="#"><span class="rollover" ></span> 
<img class="imgborder" src="images/eye.png" alt="" height="156" width="263" /></a></li>
        <li class="print-design"><a class="image" href="#"><span class="rollover" ></span> 
<img class="imgborder" src="images/rain.png" alt="" height="156" width="263" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="footer"><?php include 'footer.php'; ?></div>

</body>

</html>
```

**styling of index**

```
/* Portfolio Filter Stylesheet */

/*****Reset*****/
html, body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, ul, ol, dl, li, dt, dd, p, blockquote, pre, form, fieldset, table, th, td { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

/*****Basic Definitions*****/
body { color: #333; font: 12px/18px Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }
h1 { font-size: 1.667em; }
h2 { font-size: 1.5em; }
h3 { font-size: 1.333em; }
h4 { font-size: 1.167em; }
h5, h6 { font-size: 1em; }

a { color: #333; }
a:visited { }
a:hover { text-decoration: none; }
p, ul, ol, dl, table { margin-bottom: 18px; }
ul, ol, dd { margin-left: 36px; }

/*****Custom Classes*****/
.clearing { clear: both; }
.last { margin-bottom: 0; }
.screenReader { left: -9999px; position: absolute; top: -9999px; }

/*****Basic Layout*****/
div#container { margin: 0px auto 0; overflow: hidden; width: 860px; }



ul#filter { float: left; font-size: 16px; list-style: none; margin-left: 0px; margin-top:250px; width: 100%; font-family:Helvetica }
ul#filter li { 
    border-right: 1px solid #dedede;
    float: left;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
ul#filter li:last-child { border-right: none; margin-right: 0; padding-right: 0; }
ul#filter a { color: #333; text-decoration: none; }
ul#filter li.current a, ul#filter a:hover { color: #A1A1A1; }
ul#filter li.current a { color: #333; font-weight: bold; font-family:Helvetica }

ul#portfolio { float: left; list-style: none; margin-left:0px; margin-right:-35px; margin-top:20px;  border: 0px solid #dedede;  }
ul#portfolio li { 
    border: 0px solid #dedede; 
    float: left; 
    margin: 0 31px 20px 0; 
    padding: 0px;
    width: 263px;
    height: 156px

}
ul#portfolio a { display: block; width: 100%; }
ul#portfolio a:hover { text-decoration: none; }
ul#portfolio img { border: 0px solid #dedede; display: block; padding-bottom: 5px; }

hr { display: block; height: 1px;
    border: 0; border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 1em 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; }


    span.rollover {
    opacity: 0;
    -o-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
    background:url(images/mag.png) center center no-repeat #ffffff;

    cursor: pointer;
    height: 156px;
    width: 263px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    opacity: 0;
}

span.rollover:hover {

    opacity: 0.9;
    -o-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s; 

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000;
}
```

**about.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>psdtowebindex12323.psd</title>
        <link href="aboutstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">










</head>

    <body>

   <div id="header"><?php include 'header.php'; ?></div>


   <div id="container">

   <div id="title"><hr size=1>
   <div id="titletext">
   <br />
   About me
   <br /><br /><br />
   </div>

   <hr size=1></div>




</div>
<div class="footer"><?php include 'footer.php'; ?></div>

</body>

</html>
```

**About Style**

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */


/*****Reset*****/
html, body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, ul, ol, dl, li, dt, dd, p, blockquote, pre, form, fieldset, table, th, td { margin:0; padding: 0; }

/*****Basic Definitions*****/
body { color: #333; font: 12px/18px Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }
h1 { font-size: 1.667em; }
h2 { font-size: 1.5em; }
h3 { font-size: 1.333em; }
h4 { font-size: 1.167em; }
h5, h6 { font-size: 1em; }

a { color: #333; }
a:visited { }
a:hover { text-decoration: none; }
p, ul, ol, dl, table { margin-bottom: 18px; }
ul, ol, dd { margin-left: 36px; }

/*****Custom Classes*****/
.clearing { clear: both; }
.last { margin-bottom: 0; }
.screenReader { left: -9999px; position: absolute; top: -9999px; }




/*****Basic Layout*****/
div#container { margin: 0px auto 0; overflow: hidden; width: 860px; }

#title {

    margin-top:254px;
    width:860px;




     }

#titletext {


    width:860px;

    float:left;
    font-family:Helvetica;
    font-size:26px;
    margin-top:2px;


 }

 hr { display: block; height: 1px;
    border: 0; border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 1em 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; }

#header {


    width:100%;
    float:left;

    margin: 0px auto 0; overflow: hidden; 
    }


.footer {


    margin: 0px auto 0;

    width:860px;}
```

**Header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Creating a Filterable Portfolio with jQuery</title>
<link href="headerstyle.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" />


</head>

<body>


     <div id="contained">
            <div id="logo"><a href="http://www.altayda.com"><img src="images/Logo.png"></a></div>
            <ul id="nav">
<li><a href="http://www.altayda.com/test2">Works</a></li>
<li><a href="about.php">About me</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

        </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**Header style**

```
 body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align:left;

 }


 ul#nav {
list-style-type: none;
height: 80px;
width: 350;
margin: auto;
margin-left: 555px;
position:absolute;
top: 159px;

}
  li {
float: left;
}

 ul#nav a{

padding-right: 20px;
padding-left: 20px;
display: block;
line-height: 80px;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: Helvetica;
font-weight:bold;
font-size: 18px;
color: #371C1C;
}

ul#nav a:hover {
color: #999 ;
}








 #logo
{ 
     float: left;
     top: 161px; 
     position: absolute; 
     width: 183px;
     height: 40px;
     z-index:2;
} 

 #contained { margin: 0px auto 0; overflow: hidden; width: 860px; }



 #Contact 
{

    top: 161px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 67px;
    height: 13px;
    z-index:3;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 19px;
} 

 #Aboutme 
{

    top: 161px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 95px;
    height: 13px;
    z-index:4;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-weight: bold;
} 

 #Works 
{

    top: 161px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 53px;
    height: 13px;
    z-index:5;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: I think scrollbars does moving effect as you have margin auto at #container div.

Answer (score 1):

You have to tidy up your code, your first problem is that you are including header.php in wrong place and header.php has wrong code in it. 
1.st you have loaded all headers `(html, head, title, link)` from index.php and then you are including them again by calling header.php iside `<body>`.

then your header.php can contain only code which is valid in html `<body>` like this:

```
<div id="contained">
<div id="logo"><a href="http://www.altayda.com"><img src="images/Logo.png"></a></div>
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="http://www.altayda.com/test2">Works</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.php">About me</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

then please avoid of using `<br />` and `<hr />` iside `<ul></ul>` tag, then play again a llbit with CSS...

Try to keep your header part same in all subpages... dont do strange things with `<hr>` or `<br>` use it by CSS.